# What is the `'inf-template` file in the ob-template.el file (template for creating new babel language)

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, babel

Because the options provided by the mathematica.el file in org-contrib are quite limited, I am trying to create a new, extended, mathematica.el file. As explained on the [org language development page](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages.html#develop), I start out with the [ob-template.el](https://code.orgmode.org/bzg/worg/raw/master/org-contrib/babel/ob-template.el) file. However, the template file expects an `inf-template` file  (all occurences of template should be substituted by the target language, but I keep things general here) on linenumber 71 in the `org-babel-expand-body` function but I have no idea what kind of file that should be. Also I can not find any other `inf-...` file on my system. As I don't know much about inf files my general question is:

Someone here can share some useful information about `inf-...` files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the mean time I discovered some `inf-...` file on my system. (i.e. `inf-lisp.el`). From the contents of the file I found that the file defines an **inferior lisp mode** so that I understand that an `inf-...` file defines an optional inferior mode that can be used by the extension.